# How do I make sure the consumer only reads the most recent data for a key in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I store key value pairs in a kafka topic using librdkafka in my C++ application. For example:

<1, 100>
<2, 101>
<3, 200>

However, I may update a key value pair by sending the following message to the topic:

<1, 103>

How can I make sure that the consumer only consumes <1, 103> not <1, 100>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `seek()` in Consumer to seek to a specific offset. From this offset, you can poll messages. The polled messages may contain both `<1,100>` and `<1,103>`.

So, in order to have the latest value for a given key, you should maintain a data structure like a map where you will store the key and its value and update it with every poll using `put(key, value)` and at any given instant of time if you call `get(key)` you can get the latest value for that key that is *polled* till that instant.

---

Though, you may try to reduce `segment.ms` and `segment.bytes` for your Kafka topic and set the topic to *compaction*, you may still get multiple messages with same key. Moreover, setting `segment.ms` or `segment.bytes` to too less value is also not recommended as it leads to unncessary new segment rollovers.

---

In short, you cannot make *sure* that the consumer only *consumes* the latest value. Because, Kafka itself doesn't care about latest value, it is the client that should read the messages and get to some latest value for a key.

---

**Tip:** If you are using consumer groups (`subscribe()`) then you can use a *persistent* map to store all your previously polled key-value pairs and start polling from the last *committed* offset. This avoids seeking to beginning every time you start your application.